# Bubble sort complexity

Tags: algorithm-analysis, asymptotics, runtime-analysis, loops

So I have this code:

```
  done <- false                                     [1]
  n <- 0                                            [1]
  while (n < a) and (done = false)                  [(n+1)(1+1+1)]
    done <- true                                    [n]
    for m <- (a- 1) downto n                        [n(1+1+1+1)]
       if list[m] < list[m - 1] then                [n]
         tmp <- list[m]                             [n]
         list[m] <- list[m-1]                       [n]
         list[m - 1] <- tmp                         [n]
         done <- false                              [n]
       n <- n + 1                                   [1]
  return list                                       [1]
```

Am I doing this right? My conclusions are that the inne for-loop runs (n^2 + n) / 2 times and the outher while-loop runs n+1 times. I don't know how to properly argue for that the bubble sort has the complexity O(n^2)

Comment: What does the column of square-bracketed terms mean? Is "n2" a typo for "n^2"?

Comment: It's the ''cost'' of the operations. I did them on the best case, should they be there for the worst case? I'm supposed to also find the constant and that's why they are there. And yes, it's a typo

Comment: We have many questions on similar problems, see e.g. [tag:loops].

Answer (score -2):

There is just one loop in `for`, so the number of steps here will be proportional to `n` not n^2. The outer loop is running in a `n` proportional number of steps too. So The complexity of your algorithm is `n^2`.
***N.B.*** : When speaking complexity, you don't have to state `(n^2 + n) / 2`,just say n^2 because they are the same for big `n`s.

Comment: The number of steps in the inner loop being proportional to $n^2$ refers to the aggregate over all iterations of the outer loop. Also, $n^2$ is **not** the same as $\frac{n^2+n}2$, no matter how large $n$ might get.